# Do I Need To Replace Rotors Whenever I Replace Brake Pads?

Tags: brakes, replace, brake-rotor

I'm on a tight budget and need to replace my brake pads.  However, I've been told by my mechanic that if one does so without replacing the rotors, they will be "mismatched" and that will cause the rotor to warp and the brake pad to wear down quickly.

Is there truth to this?  I get the feeling that it's bogus, but I want to be sure

Please note: this is a different question than [this one over here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/73/should-i-resurface-or-replace-my-rotors-everytime-i-replace-brake-pads), as I am specifically asking if in normal wear situations, replacing a brake pad without replacing an undamaged rotor will cause issues due to them being "mismatched" -- which is not answered satisfactorily in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanic is right and wrong. You may not have to *replace* them, but should at least have the rotors resurfaced, or turned. This restores the braking surface for the new pads to have compatible surface. Putting new pads on used rotors is not advised and will prematurely wear the pads. The caveat is if the rotors are too thin and can not be turned, they will need to be replaced.

**This is a safety issue**, not a budget issue. When you step on the brakes, you want them to work.